# ARIA accessible radio group

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, wai-aria

I am trying to ensure that our forms are accessible.

Looking at the [W3C documentation for Radio Groups](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/radio/radio.html), oddly their example does not even *use* `input type="radio"`.  I don't understand that at all.  I have used the code below in my app, and it would appear that Voiceover reads the form correctly.  Am I correct?  And why would they you `div` tags and a lot of JS instead of simple HTML form controls?

```
<div role="radiogroup"
     aria-labelledby="stackedRadioGroup">
  <p class="radio-group-label"
     id="stackedRadioGroup">Stacked Radio Group Label</p>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input"
           type="radio"
           role="radio"
           name="stackedRadiosExample"
           id="stackedRadiosExample1"
           value="option1"
           checked>
    <label class="form-check-label"
           for="stackedRadiosExample1">
      Radio 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input"
           type="radio"
           role="radio"
           name="stackedRadiosExample"
           id="stackedRadiosExample2"
           value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label"
           for="stackedRadiosExample2">
      Radio 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input"
           type="radio"
           role="radio"
           name="stackedRadiosExample"
           id="stackedRadiosExample3"
           value="option3"
           disabled>
    <label class="form-check-label"
           for="stackedRadiosExample3">
      Radio 3 (Disabled)
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native `input[type='radio']` elements but you will still have to have a `role='radiogroup'` element to group the different items (a `fieldset` for instance)

Some people do not use native elements in order to implement custom designs easily.